# Multiple comparisons after screening -- what n to use?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

I would like to multiple comparisons correct some data, but I'm not sure what value to use for the number of comparisons in this case.

For some simple numbers, let me give an example.
Imagine I had a dataset where I wanted to know if there was a correlation between different variables, and I made 20 different plots from this data. If I visually scanned through them and selected 5 that looked the strongest, and then only did significance testing on those 5 plots, what n do I use in multiple comparisons corrections? Do I use n=5, because I only actually did 5 tests? Do I use n=20, because I scanned through 20 even though I didn't calculate test statistics on all of them? Do I use some value in between?

Whatever you answer, can you please include the logic behind your suggestion so I know why you would pick the value you do?

Thank you!

Comment: The strict answer is 20. Certainly, your quick glance is not a formal test, but you looked at them all for a reason, and made judgments accordingly. I suspect some researchers may not admit to pre-screening, and just count the 5 tested. In a formal presentation of results, it is important to reveal all the steps taken.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account that you are considering
20 datasets, if that is really the case. However, the Bonferroni method of guarding
against false discovery is based on an inequality and so may be much too conservative in practice (insisting on too small a P-value).

How many of the 20 datasets truly ever merited consideration, based on what you knew before seeing data?
If the answer is 'all', then it seems like a fishing expedition and you'd need to do additional confirmatory
study on the results you found 'significant'.

---

Here is a brief simulation to illustrate the risk of false
discovery in looking at 20 scatterplots and then testing for
significant correlations in five that look most
promising.

We look at correlations for 20 sets of data each simulated in R with 10 standard
normal x-values and 10 *independent* y-values. So they all really have population
correlation $\rho=0.$ But it happens that two of them (numbers 3 and 17) have
significant sample correlations. (Not an unusual event: at the 5% level
of significance, we'd expect one false rejection in twenty.)

```
set.seed(1)  # for reproducibility
pv = replicate(20, cor.test(rnorm(10),rnorm(10))$p.val)
which(pv < .05)
[1]  3 17
```

If you're good at judging scatterplots, presumably numbers 3 and 17
will be on your list of five most 'promising' ones. So, upon formal testing,
you'll falsely "discover" two "correlated" datasets.

The scatterplots of the two "discoveries" are shown below.  Both P-values are
below 0.02; their respective sample correlations are both about -0.736.

```
set.seed(1)  # to get same data as above
m = 20;  pv = r = numeric(m)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))  # already know we'll make w plots
for(i in 1:20) 
 {
 x = rnorm(10);  y = rnorm(10)
 r[i] = cor(x,y)
 pv[i] = cor.test(x,y)$p.val
 if(i==3 | i==17) {{plot(x, y, pch=20)}
  abline(v=0, col="green")
  abline(h=0, col="green")}
 }
r[3]; r[17]
[1] -0.7355877
[1] -0.7359006
pv[3]; pv[17]
[1] 0.0153188
[1] 0.01525276
```

[image]